# C++ Pointers, Linked List Confusion

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to build a linked list in C++.  My understanding is that the code I have created should create a node and then progressively link 4 more onto the end.  Unfortunately, while I would expect to see the cout results as "12 123 1234 12345" I'm seeing "12 12 12 12" and in my main I am unable to traverse the list - it just crashes.

I have the following code:

```
struct listNode {

    int val;
    listNode* next;

};


int nodeCount = 0;

listNode* addToEnd(listNode* node) {

    listNode* newNode = new listNode;
    newNode->val = ++nodeCount;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (node == NULL) {
        return newNode;
    }

    listNode* current = node;
    cout<<"\n\n";
    do {
        if (current->next == NULL) {
            current->next = newNode;
        }
        cout<<current->val<<"\n";
        current = current->next;
    } while (current->next != NULL);
    cout<<current->val<<endl;

}


int main()
{

    listNode* first = addToEnd(NULL);

    addToEnd(first);
    addToEnd(first);
    addToEnd(first);
    addToEnd(first);

    cout<<"Third: "<<first->next->next->val;

}
```

Any help is appreciated, as I am at wit's end!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is obvious that function `addToEnd` is wrong

```
listNode* addToEnd(listNode* node) {

    listNode* newNode = new listNode;
    newNode->val = ++nodeCount;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (node == NULL) {
        return newNode;
    }

    listNode* current = node;
    cout<<"\n\n";
    do {
        if (current->next == NULL) {
            current->next = newNode;
        }
        cout<<current->val<<"\n";
        current = current->next;
    } while (current->next != NULL);
    cout<<current->val<<endl;

}
```

Let's assume that the list already contains two nodes and consider the do-while loop inside the function. At first `current_next` != null so the following statement is executed

```
        current = current->next;
```

Now current points to the second node. Its data member `next` is equal to NULL. So the condition of the loop

```
    } while (current->next != NULL);
```

will be false and no iteration will be repeated. So we added nothing.

Also the function returns nothing if node is not equal to NULL.

Rewrite the function the following way

```
listNode* addToEnd( listNode* node ) 
{

    listNode* newNode = new listNode { ++nodeCount, NULL };

    if ( node == NULL) return newNode;

    listNode* current = node;

    while ( current->next != NULL ) current = current->next;

    current->next = newNode;

    return newNode;
    // or
    //return node;    
}
```

Take into account that this statement

```
cout<<"Third: "<<first->next->next->val;
```

outputs only the value of the third node.
If you want to output all the list you should write

```
for ( listNode *current = first; current; current = current->next ) 
{
    std::cout << current->val << ' ';
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

By the way using my function you could write in main for example the following way:)

```
listNode* first;

addToEnd( addToEnd( addToEnd( addToEnd( first  = addToEnd( NULL ) ) ) ) );
```

Comment: Why return exactly what's passed in every time?

Comment: @Josh  In fact it would be better to return the newly created node.

Comment: Actually, I like the invariant "This function returns the head of the list."  It means the caller can write `head = addToEnd(head);` without worrying whether the list was previously empty.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow node is not newly created, it's the node from somewhere in a list that the user passes in. And Ben, we have no guarantee we are getting the head of a list, all we know is that it's a node from SOMEWHERE.

Comment: @Ben Voigt  I would agree with you if each node were inserted at the beginning of the list.

Comment: @Josh Anyway it is better to return the newly created node. In this case it will be easy to append a next node.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow again, `node` is not newly created, it's the node from somewhere in some list that the user has given us. I think you are confusing `node` with `newNode`.

Comment: @Josh  No there is no confusion. In any case it is better to return the newly created node. If it is the node that is in the end of the list then it will be easy to append other nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop to get you to the last node instead of a while, and then assign the new node OUTSIDE of the loop. Trying to do it inside will result in an infinite loop (and make the code harder to read):

```
listNode* current;
for(current = node; current->next != NULL; current = current->next) ;
current->next = newNode;
```

You're also forgetting to return `newNode` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You're falling off the end of a function with non-`void` return type.  The fact that you don't use the return value does not make that ok.

6.6.3 in the Standard says that:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Comment: As I recall, it's ok if the return value isn't used in C (which is one of the tags), but the code is definitely not C.

Comment: @chris: The first sentence of the question says the code is C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Chris is right, the rules in C are different.  6.9.1 in C99 says "If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, **and the value of the function call is used by the caller**, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Deduplicator: C++ doesn't have to consider the case of missing prototypes, etc.  Its type checking is far stricter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no return statement just in case the if condition that checks `if(node==null)` fails..

Answer (score 0):

Is it against the rules to use recursive functions in your question?

Why not do...

```
void addToEnd(listNode* node){
    if(node == NULL){
        *node = new listNode;
        node->next = NULL;
        node->val = ++nodeCount;
    }else{
        addToEnd(node->next);
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    listNode* first = NULL;
    addToEnd(first); // 1
    addToEnd(first); // 2
    addToEnd(first); // 3
    addToEnd(first); // 4
    addToEnd(first); // Linked list is now 5 long
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have coded adding five nodes to a linked list that holds a node count. If anyone has advice it is welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct listNode{
 int val;
 listNode* next;
};

listNode* addToEnd(listNode*, int);

int main()
{
  listNode* first = NULL;
  listNode* temp;
  int nodeCount = 1;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     first = addToEnd(first, nodeCount);
     nodeCount++;
  }

  temp = first;

  while(temp){
     cout << temp->val << ' ';
     temp = temp->next;
  }

  temp = first;
                               //Deallocate memory
  while(temp){                 //could do memory deallocation while displaying 
     nodeToDelete = temp;      //the value of nodeCount but wanted to illustrate  
                               //both methods individually
     temp = temp->next;

     delete nodeToDelete;   
  }  

  first = NULL;                //eliminate hanging pointer

  return 0;
}

listNode* addToEnd(listNode* node, int nodeCount) 
{

  listNode* newNode = new (nothrow) listNode;
  listNode* current = node;

  if(newNode){
     newNode->val = nodeCount;
     newNode->next = NULL;
     if (node == NULL)        
        node = newNode;       

     else{          
        while (current->next != NULL) 
           current = current->next;

           current->next = newNode;          
     }
  }
  else
     cout << "error allocationg memory" << endl;

  return node;
}
```